# Cannot enable Hyper-V Enhanced sessions

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

None of the methods I've tried to enable enhanced sessions have worked. The installation is Ubuntu server 22.04 on a Windows 10 Pro, OS 19045.3803.

All the boxes for Hyper-V are checked in Windows Features. All the proper boxes are checked in Hyper-V Manager. Yet `View, Enhanced sessions` remains gray.

So what magic command am I missing?

Tried:

`DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V`, which `completed successfully`.

`Set-VM NV24 -EnhancedSessionTransportType HvSocket`, which did not return anything. But I did do `get-vm NV24 | Select-Object *` to get the following:

```
ParentCheckpointId                  :
ParentCheckpointName                :
VMName                              : NV24
VMId                                : b69bc965-4b9e-415e-a544-ec429ba57d1a
CheckpointFileLocation              : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V
ConfigurationLocation               : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V
SmartPagingFileInUse                : False
SmartPagingFilePath                 : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V
SnapshotFileLocation                : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V
AutomaticStartAction                : StartIfRunning
AutomaticStartDelay                 : 0
AutomaticStopAction                 : Save
AutomaticCriticalErrorAction        : Pause
AutomaticCriticalErrorActionTimeout : 30
AutomaticCheckpointsEnabled         : True
CPUUsage                            : 0
MemoryAssigned                      : 0
MemoryDemand                        : 0
MemoryStatus                        :
NumaAligned                         :
NumaNodesCount                      : 1
NumaSocketCount                     : 1
Heartbeat                           :
IntegrationServicesState            :
IntegrationServicesVersion          : 0.0
Uptime                              : 00:00:00
OperationalStatus                   : {Ok}
PrimaryOperationalStatus            : Ok
SecondaryOperationalStatus          :
StatusDescriptions                  : {Operating normally}
PrimaryStatusDescription            : Operating normally
SecondaryStatusDescription          :
Status                              : Operating normally
ReplicationHealth                   : NotApplicable
ReplicationMode                     : None
ReplicationState                    : Disabled
ResourceMeteringEnabled             : False
CheckpointType                      : Standard
EnhancedSessionTransportType        : HvSocket
Groups                              : {}
Version                             : 9.0
VirtualMachineType                  : RealizedVirtualMachine
VirtualMachineSubType               : Generation2
Notes                               :
State                               : Off
ComPort1                            : VMComPort (Name = 'COM 1', VMName = 'NV24') [Id = 'Microsoft:B69BC965-4B9E-415E-A
                                      544-EC429BA57D1A\8E3A359F-559A-4B6A-98A9-1690A6100ED7\0', VMId =
                                      'b69bc965-4b9e-415e-a544-ec429ba57d1a']
ComPort2                            : VMComPort (Name = 'COM 2', VMName = 'NV24') [Id = 'Microsoft:B69BC965-4B9E-415E-A
                                      544-EC429BA57D1A\8E3A359F-559A-4B6A-98A9-1690A6100ED7\1', VMId =
                                      'b69bc965-4b9e-415e-a544-ec429ba57d1a']
DVDDrives                           : {DVD Drive on SCSI controller number 0 at location 1}
FibreChannelHostBusAdapters         : {}
FloppyDrive                         :
HardDrives                          : {Hard Drive on SCSI controller number 0 at location 0}
RemoteFxAdapter                     :
VMIntegrationService                : {Guest Service Interface, Heartbeat, Key-Value Pair Exchange, Shutdown…}
DynamicMemoryEnabled                : True
MemoryMaximum                       : 1099511627776
MemoryMinimum                       : 536870912
MemoryStartup                       : 2147483648
ProcessorCount                      : 2
BatteryPassthroughEnabled           : True
Generation                          : 2
IsClustered                         : False
ParentSnapshotId                    :
ParentSnapshotName                  :
Path                                : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V
SizeOfSystemFiles                   : 73728
GuestControlledCacheTypes           : False
LowMemoryMappedIoSpace              : 134217728
HighMemoryMappedIoSpace             : 536870912
LockOnDisconnect                    : Off
CreationTime                        : 12/31/2023 2:37:56 PM
Id                                  : b69bc965-4b9e-415e-a544-ec429ba57d1a
Name                                : NV24
NetworkAdapters                     : {Network Adapter}
CimSession                          : CimSession: .
ComputerName                        : GEOLAPTOP
IsDeleted                           : False
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150620/discussion-on-question-by-geob-cannot-enable-hyper-v-enhanced-sessions); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Kindly take a look at the chat as mentioned above. Somewhere in there is my comment on adding linux-azure.

Comment: Chat is not a substitution for relevant info in OP.